# Delphi and login.Microsoftonline

Tags: javascript, delphi, authentication

I have a site that uses https://login.microsoftonline.com/ to log in.
I would like the end user not to know or need to enter the credentials so this would have to be stored in an .ini file. How can I inject the credentials from a .ini file into what is obviously a two stage js online prompt?
So Delphi would run a program with a browser that should automatically fill in the credentials.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you have a Delphi application which has to access the site you mention? How does that Delphi application access the website? Maybe using an embedded webbrowser or using a HTTP component (ICS, Indy or other). Please explain your architecture.

Comment: So, the goal is to use the Twebbrowser in Delphi to access the sites online Office 365. The idea being that the program can be run on any computer without having to put in the credentials at any time. I say this because Microsofts generic login does offer the user to stay logged in but this still requires the user to do a first login and tick the ''keep me logged in'' prompt. I have figured out that I can fill the fields with IHTMLElementCollection but I do not want this to be hardcoded. I would like it to come from the .ini file. Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Internet Explorer from your Delphi program.
I wrote a serie of blog articles about that topic.
https://francois-piette.blogspot.com/2013/05/internet-explorer-automation-part-4.html